# I have installed Apache Tomcat 7 and when I goto http://localhost:8080 in my browser, I see the following error : HTTP Status 500

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, tomcat

the error when I go to localhost:8080 in browser:

[image: the error when I go to localhost:8080 in browser]

I have tried the following by searching on google and stackoverflow but still the same error shows up:

1. Restart PC to end all the servers shutdown.
2. Manually shutdown all servers from the Windows Services
3. Also Provided the Full control access pertaining to the "no output folder" issue

Note: I am yet to start learning jsp and all Java EE stuff. I am on initial stage where one downloads the apache tomcat server and runs the hello world application.

Comment: Error 500 indicates some internal error in the server, and it can literally  have hundreds of reasons.  Have a look at its log file, and if you need help please copy the relevant section of the logfile into your question.

Comment: Check server.log for detailed error and post the message here.

Comment: where can i find the log file ?

Comment: Go to the folder where tomcat is installed, then go to logs folder.

Comment: the log file: localhost.2013-10-12
Oct 12, 2013 9:01:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Oct 12, 2013 9:01:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Oct 12, 2013 9:01:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@17aebfe')
Oct 12, 2013 9:01:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()

Comment: the rest:
Oct 12, 2013 9:01:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall Tomcat. There is something fundamentally wrong with your installation. Tomcat is pretty basic and runs "as is" out of the box, with no configuration, so something has happened to your installation. It is much easier to just reinstall it than to try and fix it.

Comment: after reinstalling, I see an empty screen when I go to localhost:8080

Comment: and when i go to 127.0.0.1 
I see, It works written there. Is that suppose to mean something ?

Comment: no, on 127.0.0.1 you are seeing apache http server (another server that you have installed). What do you mean  by empty screen? Show as server logs.